# Preenchendo um select em HTML de forma seletiva a partir de um parâmetro

Tags: html, python, django

Tenho uma view Django que faz uma consulta ao banco e retorna o resultado para um arquivo "consulta_cursos.html" onde um select é populado.

view.py

```
def consulta_cursos(request):
        if campus_id == '605':
            with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                cursor.execute("SELECT id_curso, campus, nome FROM curso WHERE campus_id = 605")
                rows = namedtuplefetchall(cursor);
                context = {'cursos': rows}
            return render(request, 'sistema/consulta_cursos.html', context)
        else:
            with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                cursor.execute("SELECT id_curso, nome FROM curso WHERE campus_id = %s", [campus_id])
                rows = namedtuplefetchall(cursor);
                context = {'cursos': rows}
            return render(request, 'sistema/consulta_cursos.html', context)
```

consulta_cursos.html

```
{% for curso in cursos %}
    <option value="{{ curso.id_curso }}">{{ curso.campus }} - {{ curso.nome }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

Entretanto, no arquivo html eu preciso que as options do select sejam diferentes de acordo com o valor do `campus_id`. Dessa forma:

```
se campus_id == '605' 
  options deve ser: '<option value="{{ curso.id_curso }}">{{ curso.campus }} - {{ curso.nome }}</option>'
senão
  options deve ser: '<option value="{{ curso.id_curso }}">{{ curso.nome }}</option>'
```

Porém não sei como fazer isso dentro de `{% for curso in cursos %} .... {% endfor %}`

Estou iniciando e esse é meu primeiro projeto, então agradeço pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode adicionar na tabela campus uma coluna com o valor booleano que indicaria como vai ser mostrado.
Ex: Você cria uma coluna bool que tenha o nome mostrar_campus(ou algo do tipo)
e no template você manda .

```
{% for curso in cursos %}
    {% if mostrar_campus %}
       <option value="{{ curso.id_curso }}">{{ curso.campus }} - {{ curso.nome}}</option>
    {% else %}
       <option value="{{ curso.id_curso }}">{{ curso.nome }}</option>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Claro, você precisa chamar mostrar campus no select.

Comment: Oi Yuri, obrigado pela resposta, mas infelizmente não posso alterar a estrutura da tabela no banco, essa não é uma opção. Agora, sua sugestão pode me ajudar se de alguma forma eu conseguir testar o `campus_id` onde vc testa `mostrar_campus`. Eu consigo acesso ao valor de `campus_id` no arquivo `consulta_campus.html` através de `sessionStorage.getItem("campus_id")`. Tem alguma forma de utilizar isso dentro do IF que testa qual option será utilizada?

Comment: Depois de algumas tentativas consegui resolver o problema utilizando a dica do Yuri e fazendo uma modificação simples na view em: `context = {'cursos': rows, "mostrar_campus": "True"}`. Adicionei ali o parâmetro que vou testar e assim consigo acessá-lo no template. Obrigado.